# How to resolve ambiguous between the following methods or properties in System.Linq.IEnumerable.ToArray() in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

[Please refer this error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atS43.png). I got an error like ambiguous between the following methods or properties while convert the **IEnumerable collection** to array like **Ranges.ToArray()** where ranges is a IEnumerable collection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to atleast provide the full error message or give us some code, until then there is no way for us to tell whats wrong.

Comment: We need full error message. The obvious method [`ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) is an extension method. If it is involved in the ambiguity, there must be additional extension methods. Which ones?

Comment: Can you show the source, please

Answer (score 4):

With used namespaces in your class there is two methods of `ToArray` with same name and signature. So compiler doesnt know which one to call.
You have to tell to compiler which to use. For this you have two possible solution.

One is removing unused namespace using from your `.cs` file.

Second is to mention namespace before method name like following.

Replace `Ranges.ToArray()` with 
`Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.CellGrid.CalcEngineHelper.ToArray(Ranges)`
Or either 
`System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(Ranges)`

Answer (score 3):

This error means that the compiler found more than one method with the same name and the same input parameters. You can then deside which one compiler should use by defining the namespace in which you'r method is. So instead of:

```
meEnumerable.ToArray();
```

You should do something like:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(meEnumerable);
```

This should work but in case it wont, you should consider removing one namespace from the file header.